# including Markdown .md files in phpdoc

Tags: phpdoc

I have a couple of Markdown.md files that I would like to include as part of the PHPDOC auto generated documentation.

I tried including the markdown extension to the phpdoc.xml file as below,

```
<extensions>
  <extension>php</extension>
  <extension>php3</extension>
  <extension>phtml</extension>
  <extension>md</extension>
</extensions>
```

but when I run the phpdoc. It says,

```
 No parsable files were found, did you specify any using the -f or -d parameter?
```

P.S The phpdoc runs fine on other php files and folders, just the markdown files are not picked up.